# Cómo trabajar con un ArrayList de Objetos

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo que trabajar en un proyecto con clases que se trata de una Universidad, en el main creo un objeto CAlumno con el cual agrego los datos de la persona, mi problema es que con este mismo objeto debo añadir las asignaturas del estudiante en la matriz que está en la clase Calumno pero es de objetos CAsignatura, no sé como poner las asignaturas con sus ID en la matriz porque son datos primitivos cuando la matriz solo admite objetos y cuando lo corro me da un error con this

```
public class Universidad {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("DNI: "+"\t"); int dni = sc.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Nombre: "+"\t"); String nom = sc.next();
      System.out.print("Direccion: "+"\t"); String dire = sc.next();
            
            CAlumno alumno = new CAlumno(dni,nom,dire);
            System.out.println("Asignaturas: ");
            
            String dec = "S";
            while(dec.equalsIgnoreCase("S") ){
                System.out.println("ID: "+"\t"); int  id = sc.nextShort();
                 System.out.print("Asignatura: "+"\t"); String asi = sc.next();
                
                alumno.añadirAsignatura(id, asi);
                System.out.print("Otra asignatura? S/N: "+"\t"); 
                dec = sc.next();
               
            }
public class CAlumno {

  int DNI;
  String nombre;
  String direccion;
  CAsignatura ID, asig;


  ArrayList<CAsignatura> asignaturas = new ArrayList<>();


  public CAlumno(int dni, String nom, String dire){

    DNI = dni;
    nombre = nom;
    direccion = dire;

  }
         if(nomb == null){
        System.out.println("ERROR: No digito su nombre ");
    }else
        nombre = nomb;
    return nomb;
}



public void añadirAsignatura( int id, String asigna){
    
    ID.asignarID(id);
    asig.asignarNombre(asigna);
    asignaturas.add(ID);
    asignaturas.add(asig);

}

public class CAsignatura {

 int id;
 String nombre;
 CConvocatoria convoca;

ArrayList<CConvocatoria> convo = new ArrayList<>();

public CAsignatura(short iden, String nom){
    

}
public void asignarID(int ide){
    id = ide;
}
public void asignarNombre(String nom){
    nombre = nom;
}

}
```

Comment: "en la matriz" cual matriz??? no definiste ninguna...

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a desmenuzar tu código... que tiene algunos problemines.

Clase **CAlumno**:
atributos:

```
CAsignatura ID, asig;
ArrayList<CAsignatura> asignaturas = new ArrayList<>();
```

la linea **CAsignatura ID, asig;**, no tiene sentido, el **id** es un número y **asig** una cadena, que aunque fuera un objeto de **CAsignatura**, carece de razón de ser, ya que tienes una lista que las contiene a todas.

después del constructor, aparece este pedazo de código fuera de un método, que debería ir en el **main** de la clase **Universidad**.

```
    if( nomb == null ) {
        System.out.println( "ERROR: No digito su nombre " );
    }
    else
        nombre = nomb;
    return nomb;
}
```

el método **añadirAsignatura** (que es el que "rompe tu programa).

```
public void añadirAsignatura( int id, String asigna ) {
   ID.asignarID( id );
   asig.asignarNombre( asigna );
   asignaturas.add( ID );
   asignaturas.add( asig );
}
```

en la primer linea (**ID.asignarID( id );**) intentas usar un método de un objeto que nunca fue instanciado (seguro que ese es el error que recibes), lo mismo pasa en la segunda.
Esto nos lleva a ver la clase **CAsignatura** que tiene un constructor que recibe parámetros pero no hace nada con ellos, y vamos a corregir para que los use.
Por lo pronto, seguimos aquí, modificamos **añadirAsignatura** para que cree una asignatura y la agregue  la lista

```
public void añadirAsignatura( int id, String asigna ) {
   CAsignatura auxiliar = new CAsignatura( id, asigna );
   asignaturas.add( auxiliar );
      // tambien podemos simplificar
   asignaturas.add( new CAsignatura( id, asigna ));
}
```

ahora veamos la clase **CAsignatura**, especificamente el constructor.

```
  // cambiamos short por int
public CAsignatura( int iden, String nom ) {
     // aquello que estaba vacio, lo llenamos
   id = iden;
   nombre = nom
}
```

los dos métodos que siguen los desechamos

```
public void asignarID( int ide ) {
   id = ide;
}

public void asignarNombre( String nom ) {
   nombre = nom;
}
```

con pocas correcciones tu código sale adelante.

Comment: Gracias fue de gran ayuda!!! Ya que con la versión simplificada puedo agregar varios objetos a la matriz asignaturas y que no estén con el mismo nombre

Comment: Un placer haberte ayudado!!